# jQuery Show/Hide Close other Elements

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a jQuery project which requires the use of show/hide functions with toggle.
I have multiple elements on the page that are hidden and shown when a link is clicked but I want each element that gets shown to close any other element.

I tried using:

```
 jQuery(".toggle").click(function()
  { 
    $('.active').not(this).toggleClass('active').next('.hidden').slideToggle(300);
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle("fast");   
  });
```

The problem with this approach is all the elements need to be together to make use of '.next' my elements are on different parts of the page.  Is there anyway I can ensure that if a user clicks on a link to show an element the other previously opened element is closed?

Many thanks

Comment: Its not possible to provide solution without HTML

Comment: <div class="link1"><a href="#" class="show">Show Item 1</a></div>
<div class="link2"><a href="#" class="show">Show Item 2</a></div>
<div class="link3"><a href="#" class="show">Show Item 3</a></div>

...some more content ..

<div class="hidden">Content for Link 1</div>
<div class="hidden">Content for Link 2</div>
<div class="hidden">Content for Link 3</div>

So as you can see I have the links to show certain elements on one part of the page and the elements themselves on another part and all I'm wanting to do is make sure that when an element is opened the others are shut.